# Removing string element off list by index id in Scala

Tags: scala

What is the best way of removing element from a list by either a comparison to the second list or a list of indices.

```
val myList = List(Dog, Dog, Cat, Donkey, Dog, Donkey, Mouse, Cat, Cat, Cat, Cat)

val toDropFromMylist = List(Cat, Cat, Dog)
```

Which the indices accordance with myList are:

```
val indices = List(2, 7, 0)
```

The end result expected to be as below:

```
newList = List(Dog, Donkey, Dog, Donkey, Mouse, Cat, Cat, Cat)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why `List(Cat, Cat, Dog)` corresponds to `List(2, 7, 0)` and not some other combination of Cats and a Dog? You simply want to remove first occurrence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `toDropFromMylist` is actually the simplest.

```
scala> myList diff toDropFromMylist
res0: List[String] = List(Dog, Donkey, Dog, Donkey, Mouse, Cat, Cat, Cat)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
myList
   .indices
   .filter(!indices.contains(_))
   .map(myList)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
myList
  .zipWithIndex
  .collect{case (x, n) if !indices.contains(n) => x}
```

Here's a complete, self-contained REPL transcript showing it working:

```
scala> case object Dog; case object Cat; case object Monkey; case object Mouse; case object Donkey
defined object Dog
defined object Cat
defined object Monkey
defined object Mouse
defined object Donkey

scala> val myList = List(Dog, Dog, Cat, Donkey, Dog, Donkey, Mouse, Cat, Cat, Cat, Cat)
myList: List[Product with Serializable] = List(Dog, Dog, Cat, Donkey, Dog, Donkey, Mouse, Cat, Cat, Cat, Cat)

scala> val indices = List(2, 7, 0)
indices: List[Int] = List(2, 7, 0)

scala> myList.zipWithIndex.collect{case (x, n) if !indices.contains(n) => x}
res1: List[Product with Serializable] = List(Dog, Donkey, Dog, Donkey, Mouse, Cat, Cat, Cat)
```

Note that I didn't use `toDropFromMylist`; that may mean I have misunderstood your question.